# HP ProCurve 2524 - CLI Command to find Fiber Transceiver's Serial Number

Tags: fiber, hp-procurve, sfp, cli, switchport

Is there any cli command allowing to check the serial numbers of the inserted mini-GBIC modules on a HP J4813A ProCurve Switch 2524?

The **show interfaces transceiver [PORT-NUMBER]** command which works on newer ProCurves unfortunately doesn't work on this model.

I tried with the **show tech** command but found no relevant info there either.

PS. I only have remote access to the device.

Answer (score 3):

`show tech transceiver` should work on the old Procurves, at least it does on the 2510 and 2600 series.

Somewhat newer Provision switches (2910, 2530, ...) support `show interfaces transceiver [n] detail` which outputs pretty much all there is.

### EDIT

Since even `show tech transceiver` doesn't seem to work on this old piece you can extract the info through SNMP MIBs:

Show all transceiver data:

```
walkMIB hpicfXcvrObjects
```

Show just serials:

```
walkMIB hpicfXcvrSerial
```

Also note that the 2500 series doesn't use GBICs or SFPs but proprietary modules (in case you want to upgrade or re-use the parts).

Comment: Unfortunately, the command "show tech transceiver" doesn't work on J4813A/ProCurve 2524 switches, so the question still remains open. The thing is, that since SNMP server is able to find that information, it should be also somehow available to retrieve manually as well.

Comment: @MartinLedermann I've added a `walkMIB` variant that should work.

Comment: I have no access to any Linux server that would be in the same network as the switch. Or is there a way to do a walkMIB from an HP router as well?

Comment: `walkMIB`is a Procurve/Provision series console command.

Comment: Indeed, the command itself is recognized, however unfortunately neither of the two objects you mentioned is being accepted. Do you think it might down to firmware?

Comment: Here's the output from the device:


sw1# walkMIB hpicfXcvrObjects
Cannot translate variable hpicfXcvrObjects.
sw1# walkMIB hpicfXcvrSerial
Cannot translate variable hpicfXcvrSerial.
sw1# show version
Image stamp:    /sw/code/build/info(s02)
                Jun 16 2009 20:25:14
                F.05.72
                422

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't read the S/N from those modules - quite possibly their hardware doesn't support that.

Comment: @MartinLedermann Possibly the objects are there but the MIBs aren't loaded. You might be able to access them with `walkmib  1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.82.1`

Answer (score 3):

Try `display transceiver interface <interface-id>`.

Comment: I don't think the 2500 series has got Comware commands yet...

Comment: Indeed they didn't. So far I've seen Comware commands only on those routers and switches that HP took over from Huawei.

Comment: Martin, I think you mean 3Com.

Answer (score -2):

I'm on firmware version 05.80 and the command I ran was `show system-information`
The MAC, Serial Number, and a few other bits of information are displayed.

Comment: The OP was asking about *transceiver* S/Ns.